# zsh autocompletion for symlinks

Tags: zsh, autocomplete

Say I have a folder `parent` with a subfolder, `subfolder` and a symbolic link `symbolic_link`.

I noticed that if my current working directory `subfolder` and I try to do `cd ../sym[TAB]`, it will not autocomplete to `cd ../symbolic_link`.

How can I enable this type of autocompletion in Zsh?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`zsh` will autocomplete a symlink for `cd` if it points to a valid directory.

```
parent $ ls -l ../symbolic_link 
lrwxrwxrwx 1 e users 1 Jan 30 23:19 ../symbolic_link -> /
parent $ cd ../symbolic_link/
                 ^^ [TAB] pressed here
parent $ ln -s /asdf ../wrong_symbolic_link
parent $ cd ../wr
                 ^^ [TAB] sound the bell here
```

Comment: Hmm, I wonder if the reason why it doesn't work for me is because my symlinks point to paths mounted on different machines on the network. It's certainly not working for me (working with ZSH 5.02)

Comment: `zsh 5.0.2` here and completion works with symbolic links pointing to directories on `nfs` and `sshfs` shares.

Comment: Thanks a lot Endre ... I will investigate this on my side. It looks like it works in some places for me too. hmm